# How do I determine whether a person use a (public) WiFi access point using WiFi sniffing?

Tags: android, wifi

I would like to distinguish the behavior of users to use a (public) WiFi access point. It would be possible to access the log files of the access point but I don't have the authority to.

Alternatively, I set this experiment for sniffing (sensing) the WiFi packets:

1. there is an access point; there are many users too
2. I set WiFi sensors built on Raspberry Pi to collect the WiFi packets from the users and AP.

Simply, As the MAC address of destination and origin were the device and the AP, the device was thought to be using the AP when it was sent and received by the data frame (not management frame).

However, there are four sub-types in the data frame. Although not sure, QoS NULL and QoS data do not appear to be using data.
[image]

In this situation, do you have any ideas to detect the usage of WiFi AP by sniffing the packet? All of data frame can be considered to determine the usage of WiFi AP?

Comment: you can use airodump-ng with filter set to specific channel and bssid to track users connected to specific access point. But If I recall correctly broadcom firmware for wifi chipset at RPI devices does not support monitor mode so I would suggest to add extra dongle to your setup. BTW, your question belongs to [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) and is off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks Maxim. I've already collected the WiFi packets by setting up the available antenna I bought. Now I have the collected database and consider the data frame types for determining the usage of WiFi access point by looking the frame only.